# Temperature Converter Perl

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I am having trouble with my code. The conversion for both Fahrenheit and Celsius will not display, and when I select "Celsius to Fahrenheit", it gives me the conversion for Fahrenheit to Celsius. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've already searched for help and have gotten nowhere. So any help would be appreciated! Here is the link if it's needed: https://crux.baker.edu/~wmorni01/WEB221_HTML/chapxx/c07case1.html

Perl script (revised):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#c07case1.cgi - Temperature conversion
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
use CGI qw(:standard);
use strict;

#variables
my ($temp, $fahConvert, $celConvert);
$temp = param('temp');
$unit = param('unit');
$fahConvert = param('fah');
$celConvert = param('cel');

#calculate
    if ($unit eq 'cel') {
        cel();
        $celConvert = ($temp - 32) * 5 / 9;

    }
    else {
        fah();
        $fahConvert = $temp * 9 / 5 + 32;
    }
sub cel {
    print "<html>\n";
    print "<head><title>Conversion from Celsius</title></head>\n";
    print "<body>\n";
    print "<h3>Celsius: $temp </h3>\n";
    print "<h3>Fahrenheit: $fahConvert </h3>\n";
    print "</body>\n";
    print "</html>\n";
}
sub fah {
    print "<html>\n";
    print "<head><title>Conversion from Fahrenheit</title></head>\n";
    print "<body>\n";
    print "<h3>Fahrenheit: $temp </h3>\n";
    print "<h3>Celsius: $celConvert </h3>\n";
    print "</body>\n";
    print "</html>\n";
}
```

HTML Script (revised):

```
<!c07case1.html>
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Washington Middle School</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Temperature Converter</H1>
<HR>
<FORM ACTION="https://crux.baker.edu/~wmorni01/cgi-bin/chap07_wendy_morningstar/c07case1.cgi" METHOD=POST>
<P><B>Temperature:</B> <INPUT TYPE=text NAME=temp></P>

<INPUT TYPE=radio NAME=unit Value=fah CHECKED>Fahrenheit to Celsius<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=radio NAME=unit Value=cel>Celsius to Fahrenheit<BR>

<P><INPUT TYPE=submit VALUE=Convert></P>
</FORM></BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your inputs are named `temp`. Start by fixing that.

```
<P><B>Temperature:</B> <INPUT TYPE=text NAME=temp></P>

<INPUT TYPE=radio NAME=unit Value=fah CHECKED>Fahrenheit to Celsius<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=radio NAME=unit Value=cel>Celsius to Fahrenheit<BR>
```

Getting the value of the two fields is done using the following:

```
my $temp = param('temp');  # Grab the temperature
my $unit = param('unit');  # "fah" or "cel"
```

Checking if the temperature is in Celcius is done using the following:

```
if ($unit eq 'cel') { ... }
```

Finally, you only calculate the converted value *after* generating the HTML that uses the variable that will be used to store the value. You could simply reverse the order of the calculation and the sub call, but it would be best if you avoided global variables in favour of parameters.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#c07case1.cgi - Temperature conversion

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw(:standard);

sub fah {
    my ($cel, $fah) = @_;
    print "<html>\n";
    print "<head><title>Conversion to Fahrenheit</title></head>\n";
    print "<body>\n";
    print "<h3>Celsius: $cel </h3>\n";
    print "<h3>Fahrenheit: $fah </h3>\n";
    print "</body>\n";
    print "</html>\n";
}

sub cel {
    my ($fah, $cel) = @_;
    print "<html>\n";
    print "<head><title>Conversion to Celcius</title></head>\n";
    print "<body>\n";
    print "<h3>Fahrenheit: $fah </h3>\n";
    print "<h3>Celsius: $cel </h3>\n";
    print "</body>\n";
    print "</html>\n";
}

{
    print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

    my $temp = param('temp');  # Grab the temperature
    my $unit = param('unit');  # "fah" or "cel"

    if ($unit eq 'cel') {
        cel( $temp, ($temp - 32) * 5 / 9 );
    } else {
        fah( $temp, $temp * 9 / 5 + 32 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, it gives me the celsius/fahrenheit and vice versa buttons correctly, but it still doesn't show the conversion.